# Is there a way to generically return a value from a set of dictionaries with different value types?

Tags: c#, generics, pattern-matching

The problem I keep hitting in my code looks like this,

```
public Dictionary<string, int> NumericProperties { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, string> TextProperties { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, string[]> CollectionProperties { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, KeyValue[]> DependencyProperties { get; set; }

public T GetProperty<T>(string name)
{
  //find out which property dictionary and return value
}
```

Is there a way to do this effectively in C#? Another thought I had was to create one `Dictionary` of type `<string, object>` and use this (I am aware that there is a none `generic` `Dictionary` type I can use too) and then it would be simply a case returning an object which could be `Pattern Matched` to find its original type.

Trouble with this option is `boxing` and `un-boxing` of variables as well as it losing its generic nature. I another option is to create an abstract base class for `Property` however since each property would consist of a name - value pair and hence would require `generics` again and we fall into the same issue of trying to return different `Types` dynamically.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: _Is_ boxing and unboxing actually an issue for you? Because you _could_ use `Dictionary<string, object>` and have `GetProperty<T>` return `(T)dict[name]`. This is as far as I know how Umbraco handles returning of properties from its Dictionary of page properties.

Comment: Simply implement `object GetProperty(string name)`

Comment: `dict<string, object>` looks like the most robust solution. I'd advise you not to bother too much about boxing/unboxing unless it's a hot path.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, just wanted to sanity check that I wasn't missing a very simple way of doing this! will go with the object dictionary option, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a dictionary of available dictionaries. Either initialize known dictionary types manually, or let this do a `SetProperty` method automatically.

```
public static Dictionary<Type, object> PropertDicts { get; } = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

public static void SetProperty<T>(string name, T value)
{
    Dictionary<string, T> typedDict;
    if (PropertDicts.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out object dict)) {
        typedDict = (Dictionary<string, T>)dict;
    } else {
        typedDict = new Dictionary<string, T>();
        PropertDicts.Add(typeof(T), typedDict);
    }
    typedDict[name] = value;
}

public static T GetProperty<T>(string name)
{
    if (PropertDicts.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out object dict)) {
        var typedDict = (Dictionary<string, T>)dict;
        if (typedDict.TryGetValue(name, out T value)) {
            return value;
        }
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

But generics work only if you know the type of a property in adavance. For completely dynamic scenarios generics are useless.